# Espeak phrase stops on the first word with os

Tags: python-3.x, espeak

why espeak can't read  long line phrase?

```
text = "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"

os.system('.\\espeak.exe %(text)s' % locals())
```

and I have only "Do...", same here:

```
os.system(".\\espeak.exe \'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?\' ")
```

what I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following way and it works for me. I am using `Windows 2013` and `Python 2.7`.

We need to join words with '_' (underscore). Somehow the word separation using blank space seems to cause problem.

```
text = "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?"  #Your original text
text = text.replace(" ", "_")                  #join words with underscore
os.system('.\\espeak.exe %(text)s' % locals()) #speak words
```

**EDIT**
Actually following works better than just  introducing special characters like "," or "_" in between words.

From  [eSpeak site](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/commands.html)

-g 
    Word gap. This option inserts a pause between words. The value is the length of the pause, in units of 10 mS (at the default speed of 170 wpm).

Here's working code:

```
text = 'Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?'
text = text.replace(' ', '_')
os.system('.\\espeak.exe  -g 20 %(text)s'  % locals())
```

Comment: got it very useful